# How to widen query results in Visual Studio Code

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code to execute my SQL Server queries. It works great except for the fact that every time I execute a query I need to widen the query results because it gets cut off. Is there a setting to change the default width of the query results box so that it doesn't reset to its small size each time I execute a query?

[image]

Comment: VSCode is a IDE, not a presentation layer. Don't treat it like the latter. If you want your data formatted nicely each time you get the data, don't use VSCode.

Comment: Alright. I may just have to switch back to Management Studio.

Comment: SSMS is an IDE as well, @NickT .

Comment: Why not, however, use ADS then, instead, which has a `Auto Size Columns` option.

Comment: Note, however, it still [won't format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nyuu5.png) to *very* wide data. That is by design. As my text in the image says "But you still can't have overly long text values, bceause this is still an IDE. If you want text formatted cells, use an application designed as a presentation layer."